# Purpose of measuring chloroform soluble extractives

Tags: food-chemistry, toxicity

I noticed that tests such as the FDA ones are measuring "chloroform soluble extractives". I understand that chloroform is toxic and its effect to human if exposed to it. But does that mean those "chloroform soluble extractives" are also as bad? i.e. if chemical-A is soluble in chloroform, does that mean chemical-A is toxic too? Otherwise, why are we measuring the "chloroform soluble extractives"?

For reference: http://www.stq-cert.com/en/news_show.php?article_id=206

Comment: There is no correlation between chloroform solubility and toxicity

Comment: @Waylander then what's the point of measuring "chloroform soluble extractives"?

Comment: @xcoder  ask the FDA not me

Comment: Why should be solvent toxicity and solute toxicity related? Potassium cyanide is water soluble. As water is not toxic, does it mean the cyanide is not toxic either ?

Comment: Really? Chloroform is a carcinogen...it should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @Achem  Chloroform is not a known carcinogen. The MSDS states " Possible cancer hazard based on tests with laboratory animals." Big difference.

Comment: Difference perspectives ...synthetic organic chemists are quite comfortable with hazardous chemicals whereas many analytical chemists are not. EPA has classified chloroform as a Group B2, probable human carcinogen. Some 30-40 years ago it was okay to have benzene in wash bottles in student organic labs and it was also okay to do qualitative analysis with mercury salts. Today it will be a nightmare in a teaching lab.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you can see an example "Closure with sealing gaskets for food containers  - U.S. FDA CFR 21 177.1210：Net chloroform soluble extractives."

For analytical testing of leacheates in samples, chloroform is not the only solvent- it is one of the solvents which is useful for representing the capability to  "extract" fat-like molecules (long chain molecules), polymers, and a wide range of other molecules particularly plasticizers. In this particluar case, the purpose is to assess if the sealing gasket in food container is able leach *potentially* toxic molecules or not over a long term in food or not.

Suppose your food in that container has oils, fats and water (like gravy or tuna fish etc.). As a chemist, one would be concerned what type molecules can leach into food after a long time  storage *from* the container. In that case, chloroform extraction test will suggest what kind of molecules might partition into the food fats from the container.

Chloroform extract does not necessarily represent toxic molecules but potentially harmful stuff. Secondly chloroform extraction is analytical chemist friendly- after extraction the analysis can be directly carried out in a gas or a liquid chromatograph for further analysis.